# How to store multiple data into postgres sql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I want to store the following data into postgres database but im not sure how. I would really appreciate any help given as I'm very new to postgres sql. I know to to insert individually but i do not know to insert dynamically with multiple data.

```
// import database
const { Client } = require('pg');
//connect to postgres
const client = new Client({
  "user": "postgres",
  "password": "root",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": "5432",
  "database": "CelebrityDB"
});

data = [
{ firstName: "tom", lastName: "hanks", age: "58"},
{ firstName: "tom", lastName: "cruise", age: "51"},
{ firstName: "bradd", lastName: "pit", age: "55"},
{ firstName: "chris", lastName: "hemsworth", age: "35"},
{ firstName: "robert", lastName: "junior", age: "52"},
];

data=data.map(function(obj) {
   return Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(key) { 
   return obj[key];
   });
});
// Insert into database
let query=format("INSERT INTO celebrity(firstName, lastName, age) VALUES %L returning id', data");
start(query);

//start function
async function start(query) {
try {
  //just connect
  await client.connect();
  let result= await client.query(query);
  console.log(result);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
} finally {
  await client.end();
}
}
```

Comment: you haven`t passed data in the clinet.query.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pg-format` is a great lightweight addition library to support inserting multiple rows with node Postgres.

Just make following changes:

`pg-format` provides the %L pattern that outputs an escaped SQL literal

```
const format = require('pg-format');
```

Converting array of objects to array of arrays because pg-format requires arrays of arrays as data.

```
data=data.map(function(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(key) { 
    return obj[key];
  });
});
```

Then store query in a variable:

```
let query=format("INSERT INTO celebity(firstName, lastName, age) VALUES %L returning id'", data);
```

And then replace this code:

```
client.query("INSERT INTO celebity(firstName, lastName, age) values()");
console.log('Data has been inserted into database');
```

with this code:

```
let result= await client.query(query);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help! i have already edited my code above to your suggestion and its still not working..

Comment: What is the error you are receiving, also what does console.log(result) says?

Comment: it says `throw new Error('too few arguments');`

Comment: The `format()` function params are wrong. You've created a `string` of the query and the 2nd argument that's meant to be passed to the function. Change to `format("INSERT.... returning id'", data)`